# Rails 4 require and permit for update PUT request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I have a rails controller with an update method:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @segment.update(segment_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @segment, notice: 'Segment was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.json { render json: @segment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

The segment_params method:

```
  def segment_params
    params.require(:segment).permit(:name, :description, :f_30_day_estimated_reach, :tags)
  end
```

I'm unsure as to how to make the actual request to be accepted by rails. I'm using Postman (Google Chrome) to make the request. I'm making a `PUT` request to `localhost:3000/segments/2677.json` with the segment info as JSON. Is this the correct way of doing it? Or would this be a URL param? Not quite sure how to format it as a URL param.

Comment: If you use `GET` it will be url params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions. This was an oversight on my part. I thought POSTMAN would specify the Content-Type HTTP Header as application/json because I was posting JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You should not make changes to server data via a GET request. For the reasoning behind this see: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html section 9.1.1 - bascally GET and HEAD request should always be safe.

The method you are using right now is actually a good one. My only suggeston - if you really want to follow the HTTP spec would be to use PATCH instead of PUT for partial updates. The semantics for PATCH are essentially that rather than being idempotent like PUT it does delta updates like what you are doing. See : http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html for more info on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the server log after the PUT and you'll see something like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zzzz", "segment"=>{"name"=>"My Segment Name", "description"=>"Something", "f_30_estimated_reach"=> "I dont know", "tags"=> "tag1 tag2 tag3" }
```

The key "segment" must be present with your data as value. I assume that "tags" isn't an array, or represent an associated model.

If not, let say 'tags is an array', you must call permit this way:

```
params.require(:segment).permit(:name, :description, :f_30_day_estimated_reach, :tags [])
```

If tags is an associated model and you update the 'name' field:

```
params.require(:segment).permit(:name, :description, :f_30_day_estimated_reach, tags: {:name})
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4, the recommended HTTP action for an update action is the `PATCH` method. If you run `rake routes` in your Terminal, you'll see that the update action is linked to the `PATCH` action by default (assuming that you're using the `resources` method.

Rails is very opinionated about how you pass parameters in, and uses the concept of "strong params" to sanitize and validate your parameters as they're passed in from your form to your controller. This is a good primer on the topic (https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters), but I'm assuming you're trying to pass tags in as a collection (array in this case).

```
def segment_params
  params.require(:segment).permit(:name, :description, :f_30_day_estimated_reach, :tags => [])
end
```

As Alejandro Babio said, if you're using an associated model then it you need to permit tags along with their model attributes that you've defined in your database migration file for the tags table. For example:

```
def segment_params
  params.require(:segment).permit(:name, :description, :f_30_day_estimated_reach, :tags => {:name, :created_at, :updated_at})
end
```

It also might be a good idea to see what your params actually looks like by calling `segment_params.inspect` before `@segment.update(segment_params)`. If `:tags` does not show up in the inspect method output, then it's not being passed into your strong params correctly.